# How can i keep time in a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, date, time, format

okay, my table has 7 columns,

```
bno     VARCHAR(45) PK  NN
bdate       DATE            NN
btime       TIME            NN
duedate     DATE            NN
memo        VARCHAR(100)        NN 
vcode       INT     FK  NN      
status          TINYINT         NN
```

I need `btime` column to keep the time, for example 01:30:23 PM. how can I do this? how to write `INSERT` and `UPDATE` queries to save and update time?

sorry, i forgot to mention that i take time from a jTextField in NetBeans. it shows the current time with AM/PM

Comment: the same way you write other queries? what is your actual question?

Comment: please consider to acceppt an answer (click tick mark on the left) if it actually answered your question

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO tablename (mytime) VALUES (NOW())
UPDATE tablename SET mytime=NOW() WHERE id=1 LIMIT 1
```